# Varying results for Google Geocode API based on server making request

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We host our site (http://www.trybaker.com) on AWS in the N. California region.  We have an AWS setup with several app servers all located in the same availability zone.  Earlier today we realized that a request to Google's Geocode API from any of those servers was returning ZERO_RESULTS.  This is the same whether it is being done from the app code or via curl on the command line.  The lookup URL is:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=11975+E+40th+Ave%2C+Denver+CO%2C+80239

Whenever any of servers located in that availability zone do that lookup we get a ZERO_RESULTS result.  Pasting that URL into the browser works as expected returning a full set of results.

Over the course of debugging I took it upon myself to fire up an instance in a different region...in this case N. Virginia.  Attempting to hit that same url via curl on the command line returns the expected results.  This seems to indicate that the issue has something to do with the location of our servers.  Has anybody run into this in the past?  Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: my company is running into the same problem. There is an open issue with Google, https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10585&q=apitype%3AGeocoder&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Comment: And us as well. This is a major outage for us and I am amazed google hasn't reported any issues on their status page

Comment: At least they got it up and running just a few hours later.  I'm sure their deployment process is significantly more complicated than ours :D

Comment: Yes, there was an issue during that time when the % of requests getting ZERO_RESULTS increased in some regions. This was reported in http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10585

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geocoding API issue ZERO\_RESULTS in api response but works in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779030/geocoding-api-issue-zero-results-in-api-response-but-works-in-browser)